# eclipse - search only opens one file at a time

Tags: eclipse, search

In eclipse, when i do a global search (open search dialog), i can get a list of results.

However, when i open these results, eclipse will ever only open one file at a time. That is, given results:

```
A
B
C
```

i can double-click on `A` and will see that file. However, if i then double-click on `B`, file `A` will be closed, and replaced by `B`

I'd like to be able to read both files (or as many files as i care to double-click on)... how can i do this?

Answer (score 24):

1. Go to Preferences > General > Search
2. Unselect the box marked "Reuse editors to show matches"
3. Click Ok.

That should do it.

Comment: There ought to be a way for somebody else -- or the community -- to accept an answer, even when the asker has wandered off and forgotten about it.

Comment: The wording of this Eclipse preference is really unintuitive, imo - though it works.